# Konsole Colour Scheme

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, konsole

I use konsole 2.8.5 on Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit.
I wish to make some changes to the colour scheme.

I would like to see the text before the $ symbol in a different colour, other than the regular text colour.

I don`t know whether this can be done, but I would like to give it a try.

All suggestions are welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have colorized prompt in console you could set the PS1 environment variable.

You can start with prompt basics [here](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-prompt-basics), then check out [this amazing explanation](http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux) on how to use up to 256 colors!

EDIT: I can also give the colored PS1 I use:

```
PS1='\e[1m\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

[image: Colored Prompt]

Answer (score 1):

This site provides a PS1 environmental variable generator,
http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html

It is easier to use but limited functionality.